# Jssor - Click on thumbnail show that photo in Slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider, jssor

I build a little Template and on this there is a Jssor Slider and the pictures on this Slider are in thumbnails too. 
By click on the thumbnail I want that this picture shows in the slider. How can i make that with Jquery.

The code at the moment:

```
var a_td_pic = [$("#tecdoc_bild1_thumb").attr("src"), $("#tecdoc_bild2_thumb").attr("src"), $("#tecdoc_bild3_thumb").attr("src"), $("#tecdoc_bild4_thumb").attr("src"),$("#hersteller_logo_thumb").attr("src")]; 
var a_ntd_pic = [$("#detailbild1_thumb").attr("src"), $("#detailbild2_thumb").attr("src"), $("#detailbild3_thumb").attr("src"), $("#detailbild4_thumb").attr("src"), $("#detailbild5_thumb").attr("src"),$("#hersteller_logo_thumb").attr("src")]; 
a_td = cleanArray(a_td_pic);
a_ntd = cleanArray(a_ntd_pic);
var check = [$("#tecdoc_bild1_thumb").attr("src"), $("#tecdoc_bild2_thumb").attr("src"), $("#tecdoc_bild3_thumb").attr("src"), $("#tecdoc_bild4_thumb").attr("src")];  
if (check[0] == "" && check[1] == "" && check[2] == "" && check[3] == "") {

    // Kein TecDoc 
    console.log("Kein TecDoc Bild");
    $("#thumb").html("");
    var i_3 = 0; 
    while (a_ntd[i_3]) {
        console.log(a_ntd[i_3]); 
        $("#thumb").append('<div id="thumb_'+i_3+'"><img src="'+a_ntd[i_3]+'" class="thumb" /></div>'); 
        i_3 ++; 
    }
    if(a_ntd.length > 3) {
            // Wenn mehr als 3 Bilder vorhanden sind wird auf Thumbnail Slider angepasst
    }
            var i_4 = 0; 
    while (a_td[i_4]) {
        $("#thumb_"+i_4).click(function() {

        });
        i_4 ++;
    }
}   

else {
    console.log("TecDoc Bild"); 
    $("#thumb").html("");
    var i_3 = 0; 
    while (a_td[i_3]) {
        console.log(a_td[i_3]); 
        $("#thumb").append('<div id="thumb_'+i_3+'"><img src="'+a_td[i_3]+'" class="thumb"/></div>');
        i_3 ++; 
    }
    if(a_td.length > 3) {
        // Wenn mehr als 3 Bilder vorhanden sind wird angepasst auf den Slider
    }
    var i_4 = 0; 
    while (a_td[i_4]) {
        $("#thumb_"+i_4).click(function() {
            $("#pic_"+i_4).css("left","0px");  
        });
        i_4 ++; 
    }
}
```

Best regards

Comment: What have you tried? Provide some code... We're not gonna build your stuff for you.

Comment: is this your class assignment?

Comment: I paste the code in the post at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the 3rd thumbnail was clicked, please use the following code to display the 3rd slide.

jssor_slider1.$GoTo(2);
//or
jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(2);